# Is it impossible to let-bind a composite lens?

Tags: haskell, functor, haskell-lens, unification

I'm having trouble understanding whether the following is feasible by helping the type-checker, or just outright impossible.
The setup is slightly arbitrary, I just need some nested data types with lenses, here called `A`, `B`, `C`.

My problem is that I can use the composite lens `(bLens . a)` if I immediately call something like `view` using it, but if I try to let-bind it and give it a name, I get error messages.

```
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleContexts #-}
{-# LANGUAGE MonoLocalBinds #-}
{-# LANGUAGE RankNTypes #-}
{-# LANGUAGE ScopedTypeVariables #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TemplateHaskell #-}

module Debug where

import Control.Eff
import Control.Eff.Reader.Strict
import Control.Lens

data A = A

data B = B
  { _a :: A
  }
makeLenses ''B

data C = C
  { _b :: B
  }
makeLenses ''C

askLensed :: ( Member (Reader r) e ) => Lens' r a -> Eff e a
askLensed l = view l <$> ask

works :: ( Member (Reader C) e ) => Lens' C B -> Eff e A
works bLens = do
  askLensed (bLens . a)

doesNotWork :: ( Member (Reader C) e ) => Lens' C B -> Eff e A
doesNotWork bLens = do
  let compositeLens = bLens . a
  askLensed compositeLens

doesNotWork2 :: ( Member (Reader C) e ) => Lens' C B -> Eff e A
doesNotWork2 bLens = do
  let compositeLens :: Lens' C A = bLens . a
  askLensed compositeLens

butThisIsFine :: Lens' C B -> Lens' C A
butThisIsFine bLens =
  let compositeLens = bLens . a in compositeLens
```

The error messages being:

```
• Could not deduce (Functor f0) arising from a use of ‘bLens’
  from the context: Member (Reader C) e
    bound by the type signature for:
               doesNotWork :: forall (e :: [* -> *]).
                              Member (Reader C) e =>
                              Lens' C B -> Eff e A
    at /home/.../.stack-work/intero/interoW51bOk-TEMP.hs:32:1-62
  The type variable ‘f0’ is ambiguous
  Relevant bindings include
    compositeLens :: (A -> f0 A) -> C -> f0 C
```

and:

```
• Couldn't match type ‘f0’ with ‘f’
    because type variable ‘f’ would escape its scope
  This (rigid, skolem) type variable is bound by
    a type expected by the context:
      Lens' C A
    at /home/.../.stack-work/intero/interoW51bOk-TEMP.hs:35:3-25
  Expected type: (A -> f A) -> C -> f C
    Actual type: (A -> f0 A) -> C -> f0 C
• In the first argument of ‘askLensed’, namely ‘compositeLens’
  In a stmt of a 'do' block: askLensed compositeLens
  In the expression:
    do let compositeLens = bLens . a
       askLensed compositeLens
• Relevant bindings include
    compositeLens :: (A -> f0 A) -> C -> f0 C
```

I have tried adding type signatures, with explicit quantification of the `f` and `Functor` constraints , but to no success so far.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A rule of thumb that simplifies many things is to not take `Lens` (or `Lens'`, or `Setter` etc.) as function arguments unless you really need it the optic-polymorphism, but instead take the `ALens` (or `ALens'` or `ASetter`) version, which avoids the Rank-2 polymorphism issues.

The problem is that if you give `compositeLens` a name in a `do` block, then it must have a type that can't be inferred from its context anymore. But `Lens' C A` is a polymorphic type under the hood, and this complicates type inferrence considerably. It *is* actually ok if you give an explicit signature:

```
doesActuallyWork2 :: ( Member (Reader C) e ) => Lens' C B -> Eff e A
doesActuallyWork2 bLens = do
  let compositeLens :: Lens' C A
      compositeLens = bLens . a
  askLensed compositeLens
```

Your version `doesNotWork2` didn't work because an definition with in-line signature is flipped over to the RHS, like

```
doesNotWork2 :: ( Member (Reader C) e ) => Lens' C B -> Eff e A
doesNotWork2 bLens = do
  let compositeLens = bLens . a :: Lens' C A
  askLensed compositeLens
```

...where `compositeLens` again tries to specialise the just-given type to one particular functor, which can't be done.

The more straightforward solution is to avoid this local polymorphism entirely, which yout don't actually need: if you take an `ALens'` as the argument, the local binding automatically takes on the monomorphic type: like

```
worksEasily :: ( Member (Reader C) e ) => ALens' C B -> Eff e A
worksEasily bLens = do
  let compositeLens = bLens . a
  askLensed compositeLens
```

Actually not quite this; it turns out you don't want `ALens'` here but `Getting`. The easiest way to find this out it to remove the signature to `askLensed` and let the compiler tell you what it infers, then work backwards from that.

```
askLensed :: ( Member (Reader r) e ) => Getting a r a -> Eff e a
askLensed l = view l <$> ask

worksEasily :: ( Member (Reader r) e ) => Getting A r B -> Eff e A
worksEasily bLens = do
  let compositeLens = bLens . a
  askLensed compositeLens
```

Comment: Thanks for the thorough answer! I had a hunch `doesNotWork2` failed for the reason you mentioned, and I did not know about the `A...` family. I probably don't need the rank-2 polymorphism for most of my use cases, so this is perfect!